# Scope en Laravel con tabla relacionada

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, filtro, scope

estoy atascado en un filtro:

Estas son mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi modelo para Movimiento

```
public function factura() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Factura'); 
}

public function cuenta() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cuenta'); 
}

public function centroCosto() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CentroCosto'); 
}

public function scopeFfecha($query, $fdesde=NULL, $fhasta=NULL)
{
    if ($fdesde)
        $query=$query->where('fechaContable','>=',$fdesde);
    if ($fhasta)
        $query=$query->where('fechaContable','<=',$fhasta);
    return $query;
}
```

y para mi controlador:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $fdesde= $request->get('fdesde');
    $fhasta=$request->get('fhasta');
    $movimientos=Movimiento::wherecuenta_id($id)->with('factura')
                            ->ffecha($fdesde,$fhasta)
                            ->get();
    return view('resultado.show',compact('movimientos'));   
}
```

El problema es que como el campo `fechaContable` no está en la tabla movimientos el filtro falla y devuelve la colección de datos completa.

Ya comprobé los parámetros de fecha que devuelve $request y están correctos.

Necesito mostrar todos los registros de `movimientos` que cumplen la condición de `cuenta_id`y el rango de `fechaContable`, por lo que si invierto la relación (filtrar primero la fecha de factura) de todas formas tendré el mismo problema porque deberé filtrar por el campo `cuenta_id` de la tabla movimientos.

Comment: has intentado utilizar en la consulta con whereDate ?? A mi me paso en un proyecto que por no coincidir correctamente los formatos entre fechas la consulta no me generaba resultados.

Comment: Otro comentario, no estoy seguro si sql soporta el >= o <=,  por lo que la consulta lo aria de esta forma. whereDate(fechaContable, '>',  Carbon::parse($fdesde)->format('Y-m-d'))->where(fechaContable,  Carbon::parse($fdesde)->format('Y-m-d'))->get();

Comment: Efectivamente @AlbertoOrtega el where era parte del problema, se debe usar whereDate para ques sólo considere la parte de la fecha al comparar, de otra forma toma la hora tanto del campo almacenado como de la variable pasada al filtro, con lo que se produce un desfase en los resultados mostrados.

Comment: De nada fue un placer ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por los comentarios, finalmente encontré la solución, la dejo por si le sirve a alguien más.

El filtro debe colocarse en el modelo de `Factura`, de la siguiente forma (efectivamente como indica Alberto Ortega se debe usar whereDate o de otra forma interfiere la hora en la consulta y los resultados son erróneos):

```
public function scopeFfecha($query, $fdesde=NULL, $fhasta=NULL)
{
    if ($fdesde)
        $query=$query->whereDate('fechaContable','>=',$fdesde);
    if ($fhasta)
        $query=$query->whereDate('fechaContable','<=',$fhasta);
    return $query;
}
```

y en el controlador se usa `whereHas`de la siguiente forma:

```
$movimientos=Movimiento::wherecuenta_id($id)
                    ->whereHas('factura',function($q) use ($fdesde,$fhasta){
                        $q->ffecha($fdesde,$fhasta);})
                     ->get();
```

Aproveché también para ordenarlo por la fecha de la factura, así que finalmente quedó de esta forma:

```
$movimientos=Movimiento::wherecuenta_id($id)
                    ->whereHas('factura',function($q) use ($fdesde,$fhasta){
                        $q->ffecha($fdesde,$fhasta);
                    })
                    ->join('facturas','movimientos.factura_id','=','facturas.id')
                    ->orderBy('facturas.fechaContable','DESC')
                    ->get();
```